# Getting Control Name from String and then use ControlName.Text to add to datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, type-conversion, controls

I'm trying to add values from TextBoxes to a DataTable so that I can check for null values (and later, duplicate values)

I am able to add Rows to the table directly from the TextBoxes, but when I try and dynamically add the last TextBox(es) my code is adding a String rather than the required Value as below:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("CheckforNulls");
            dt.Columns.Add("ColumnToCheck", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(txtSettingsOneValue.Text.ToLower());
            dt.Rows.Add(txtSettingsTwoValue.Text.ToLower());

            //ComboBox that has a value between 1 and 12
            int x = int.Parse(cbSettingsThreeValue.SelectedItem.ToString());

            int i = 1;
            while (i <= x)
            {
                string threeValue = "txtSettingsThreeValue" + i + ".Text.ToLower()";

                dt.Rows.Add(threeValue);

                i++;
            }
```

At the moment my DataTable looks like below after running through

```
            ColumnToCheck
            V
            S
            txtSettingsThreeValue1.Text.ToLower()
```

Is there any way of converting the string to an Existing TextBox Name and then adding it to the Value of the TextBox to the DataTable?

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually [Find the control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) when it is required to use `.Text` property associated with control.

Problem lies here:

```
string threeValue = "txtSettingsThreeValue" + i + ".Text.ToLower()";
```

Find your control from `From control collection`, cast it as textbox and get access to Text property.

```
TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtSettingsThreeValue" + i, false).FirstOrDefault();
string threeValue = txtBox.Text.ToLower();
```

If your control is nested inside some other controls then use `true`.

See the description on MSDN reference above.

Answer (score 1):

find control by name :

```
private Control FindControlByName(string name)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls) 
    {
       if (c.Name == name)
           return c; //found
    }
    return null; //not found
 }
```