# Get a usercontrol's child control by name in C#

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a usercontrol which contains some `ComboBoxes`. I've set their `Modifiers` property to `Protected Internal` so that I can access them in my main form's code.

I'm trying to get their names by string. I Tried this

```
ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox )ucMyUserControl.Controls.Find("cmb" + restOfTheName, false).FirstOrDefault();
```

as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885627/getting-control-name-from-string-and-then-use-controlname-text-to-add-to-datatab?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggested. But it returns `null`.

How can I make it works?

Comment: Check my solution and tell me if this helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)ucMyUserControl.Controls.Find("cmb" + restOfTheName, 
                                                   true).FirstOrDefault();
```

If your `ID` is correct this will return your control. It is possible `ComboBox` to be nested in other control in the user control. The second parameters is `searchAllChilds` flag, because of that the param should be true to search in all the controls in the `UserControl`.

Comment: Easy solution which I haven't thought about! Thanks!